# Nuxt 3 useFetch refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I want to use `useFetch` to render some content with SSR and it works well when the app is mounted. The markup is generated on the server as expected. When I use `nuxt-link`, to avoid a page refresh, I get a CORS error. How do I make sure the fetch happen on the nuxt server?

This is in my app.vue

```
<script setup>
const route = useRoute();

const { data, refresh } = await useFetch(`https://thesite.net/` + route.path);

watch(
  () => route.path,
  () => refresh()
);
</script>
```

Comment: Is thesite.net your site? You may not need to specify full url. What's the purpose of useFetch here?

Comment: The full url was added temporarily for a quick test. The data is coming from another service but it will run on the same domain so cors shouldn't be an issue when is deployed. I was wondering if there is a way to let the refresh happen on the nuxt server rather than from the client. Hope it makes sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't force `useFetch` to happen on server when you navigate through NuxtLink.
Server rendering only occurs when you first load the app, then it's all SPA rendering, so client side only.

If you need to fix your CORS, you'll have to add your localhost url to the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header so you can use it while developping.

Comment: I thought it was the case, thanks for confirming